# Tail bound of normally distributed variable by a exponential

Tags: probability, upper-lower-bounds, gaussian

I have $z \sim N(0,n)$

By my script, a random variable $\xi \sim N(0,1)$ satisfies the following tail bound for all $t \ge 0$,
$$P(\xi \ge 0) \le e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}$$

Goal of the derivation is to come up to :
$$P(|z_i| > \sqrt{tn}) \le 2e^{-\frac{t}{2}}$$

What I tried is first to standardize $z_i$ as $\frac{z_i - 0}{n} \sim N(0,1)$.

From there,  I get that for $\frac{z_i - 0}{n} \sim N(0,1)$ and every $t \ge 0$:
$$P(\frac{z_i}{n} > t) \le e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}$$
which is the same as:
$$P(z_i > tn) \le e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}$$

What I don't see is, how they manage to square root RHS of inequality under probability term and progress it to arrive to final goal.

Comment: $\frac{z_i - 0}{\sqrt{n}} \sim N(0,1)$ instead - when you divide a random variable by constant $C$, variance goes down by $C^2$

Comment: @Pig Yeah, my bad, I oversaw this rule, but what comes after this? I cannot just say $\sqrt{t} \ge 0$ instead of $t \ge 0$

Comment: You can by substitution

Comment: There is still a 2 in front of exponential at the end solution, which cannot be resolved

Comment: You want to handle $|z| > stuff$. This is equivalent to $z > stuff$ or $z < -stuff$ - exactly where the 2 comes from.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Do you want to give that as an official answer so I can endorse it as an official one?